# Large delay in Windows functions such as left-clicking taskbar icons or right-clicking start menu items

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, context-menu, nvidia-geforce

I'm using a laptop with a Windows 10 Pro OS and an Nvidia GeForce 150M graphics card. I recently had an error within my MBR that I managed to fix through various command line commands and system restoring, which culminated with me resetting the registry to default. I also identified OneDrive as the reason my laptop got so messed up in the first place and have since disabled all of its features.

I have one really annoying residual problem however and I'm not quite sure how to fix it. Certain windows functions have considerable lag. For instance, when I left-click the WiFi or sound icon in the taskbar, right-click on the desktop or right-click start menu icons. All of these actions take well over a minute to execute. My theory is that there is some internal Windows process that need to be ameliorated but I don't have enough knowledge of Win10 to figure out what. All help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Run adwcleaner.exe from trusted source and report any significant changes. Otherwise a full result of MSinfo32 unlinked is a start to review status saved as .inf file

Comment: I ran adwcleaner from malwarebytes which cleared 2 PUPs but there are no significant improvements. Actually now I have a new issue where pages are taking forever to load on my browser. I'm not sure what the second part of your comment means. Are you asking for my system information? If so, how can I save it as an .inf file? MSinfo32 only saves as .nfo by default.

Comment: UPDATE: I disabled Daemon Tools and my system seems to be working normally for the time being. The same behavior occurred when I disabled OneDrive (The system worked as normal and then eventually went back to exhibit the lag issues I mentioned in my OP). I think some programs might have gotten corrupted when I was trying to resolve issues with the MBR.

Comment: UPDATE: Machine is back to exhibiting the same issues

Comment: Run disk check? Spinrite?

Comment: I ran chkdsk from the command line and it returned no errors.

Comment: .inf file needs to be analyzed  (>1MB) (msinfo32)

Comment: Hey I'm not quite sure how I'd get the .inf file. Would I just change the extension on the auto-generated .nfo file from msinfo32?

Comment: Brain fart. I meant .nfo file which opens up by default with msinfo32